# Error 324 Empty response after create wp-config in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, installation, apache2.2

I'm trying to install wordpress on my apache server and always after create wp-config.php file is Error 324 Empty respone. I don't know why because if wp-config.php not exits everything works.
I thing it's server configuration problem

It's plain wordpress 3.5.1, MySQL 5.1.49, Apache/2.2.16 (Debian), php 5.3.3

Comment: You'd better link the wp-config.php file or post the code of it. ( hide your passwords )

Comment: It's standard wp-config.php. downloaded wordpress from http://wordpress.org/. Nothing unusuall

Comment: Does the website has the rights to execute and write files on the server?

Answer (score 0):

Resolve Error 324 by following the solutions given in this video tutorial https://vimeo.com/60824619

Best of luck!

Comment: It is not a Chrome problem because the same error is in every browser. It's a server side problem. I'm using apache2.2 but i don't know what what what what ....